# Need to scroll fixed table header horizontally along with its rows

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table created using divs. The table header is fixed when we scroll down the page. Since the table is too wide to fit in the viewport. So I am having an option to scroll it horizontally. But the issue with table's header. When we scroll down the page, the table header becomes sticky and therefore it is can't be scrolled horizontally along with table body. Is there any workaround so that we can scroll fixed header horizontally with its rows?

I know that there are several similar questions already asked on sto and I followed them too but none of them actually did work for me. My question is different in the sense that it freezes table header when you scroll the page and not on initially.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Need to set the variable outside the function, otherwise the position will keep changing on scroll
  var head_pos = $(".customer_headings").offset().top;

  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(".customer_headings").length)
    {
      win_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      // Get the width of the container
      cont_width = $(".customers_table").width();

      if(win_scroll > head_pos)
      {
     $(".customer_headings").css({"position":"fixed","top":"0px","width":cont_width, "z-index":"10"})
      }
      else
      {
        $(".customer_headings").css({"position":"static"})
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.customers_table_cont {
  border:1px solid red;
  width:1200px;
}

.customers_table {
  overflow-x:auto;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}

.customer_headings {
  background-color:#4c4c4c;
  color:#ffffff;
  white-space:nowrap;
  display:inline-block;
}

.customer_row {
  white-space:nowrap;
  display:inline-block;
}

.customer_column {
  width:250px;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:15px;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

.customer_heading_dropdown {
  list-style-type:none;
  background:#ffffff;
  border-radius:0px 0px 5px 5px;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #5a5a5a;
  display:block;
  padding:10px 5px;
  position:absolute;
  top:34px;
  left:18px;
  z-index:99999;
}

.customer_heading_dropdown li {
  border-radius:5px;
  color:#525252;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-weight:normal;
  line-height:14px;
  margin:5px;
  padding:5px 10px 5px 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Customers Table</h1>

<div class="customers_table_cont">
  <div class="customers_table">
    <div class="customer_headings">
      <div class="customer_column">Company</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Name Heading is too long to fit here and shrinks</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Product
      <ul class="customer_heading_dropdown">
      <li>Remove Column</li>
      <li>Move Column Left</li>
      <li>Move Column Right</li>
      <li>Widen Column</li>
      <li>Narrow Column</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="customer_column">Site</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Date Added</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Salesperson</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Quote</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Country</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Progress</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Estimate</div>
  </div>
    <div class="customer_row">
      <div class="customer_column">Dell</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Sachin Sharma</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Laptop</div>
      <div class="customer_column">dell.com</div>
      <div class="customer_column">31-03-2020</div>
      <div class="customer_column">David</div>
      <div class="customer_column">150</div>
      <div class="customer_column">India</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Good</div>
      <div class="customer_column">500</div>
    </div>
    <div class="customer_row">
      <div class="customer_column">Dell</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Sachin Sharma</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Laptop</div>
      <div class="customer_column">dell.com</div>
      <div class="customer_column">31-03-2020</div>
      <div class="customer_column">David</div>
      <div class="customer_column">150</div>
      <div class="customer_column">India</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Good</div>
      <div class="customer_column">500</div>
    </div>
    <div class="customer_row">
      <div class="customer_column">Dell</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Sachin Sharma</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Laptop</div>
      <div class="customer_column">dell.com</div>
      <div class="customer_column">31-03-2020</div>
      <div class="customer_column">David</div>
      <div class="customer_column">150</div>
      <div class="customer_column">India</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Good</div>
      <div class="customer_column">500</div>
    </div>
    <div class="customer_row">
      <div class="customer_column">Dell</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Sachin Sharma</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Laptop</div>
      <div class="customer_column">dell.com</div>
      <div class="customer_column">31-03-2020</div>
      <div class="customer_column">David</div>
      <div class="customer_column">150</div>
      <div class="customer_column">India</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Good</div>
      <div class="customer_column">500</div>
    </div>
    <div class="customer_row">
      <div class="customer_column">Dell</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Sachin Sharma</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Laptop</div>
      <div class="customer_column">dell.com</div>
      <div class="customer_column">31-03-2020</div>
      <div class="customer_column">David</div>
      <div class="customer_column">150</div>
      <div class="customer_column">India</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Good</div>
      <div class="customer_column">500</div>
    </div>
    <div class="customer_row">
      <div class="customer_column">Dell</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Sachin Sharma</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Laptop</div>
      <div class="customer_column">dell.com</div>
      <div class="customer_column">31-03-2020</div>
      <div class="customer_column">David</div>
      <div class="customer_column">150</div>
      <div class="customer_column">India</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Good</div>
      <div class="customer_column">500</div>
    </div>
    <div class="customer_row">
      <div class="customer_column">Dell</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Sachin Sharma</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Laptop</div>
      <div class="customer_column">dell.com</div>
      <div class="customer_column">31-03-2020</div>
      <div class="customer_column">David</div>
      <div class="customer_column">150</div>
      <div class="customer_column">India</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Good</div>
      <div class="customer_column">500</div>
    </div>
    <div class="customer_row">
      <div class="customer_column">Dell</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Sachin Sharma</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Laptop</div>
      <div class="customer_column">dell.com</div>
      <div class="customer_column">31-03-2020</div>
      <div class="customer_column">David</div>
      <div class="customer_column">150</div>
      <div class="customer_column">India</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Good</div>
      <div class="customer_column">500</div>
    </div>
    <div class="customer_row">
      <div class="customer_column">Dell</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Sachin Sharma</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Laptop</div>
      <div class="customer_column">dell.com</div>
      <div class="customer_column">31-03-2020</div>
      <div class="customer_column">David</div>
      <div class="customer_column">150</div>
      <div class="customer_column">India</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Good</div>
      <div class="customer_column">500</div>
    </div>
    <div class="customer_row">
      <div class="customer_column">Dell</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Sachin Sharma</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Laptop</div>
      <div class="customer_column">dell.com</div>
      <div class="customer_column">31-03-2020</div>
      <div class="customer_column">David</div>
      <div class="customer_column">150</div>
      <div class="customer_column">India</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Good</div>
      <div class="customer_column">500</div>
    </div>
    <div class="customer_row">
      <div class="customer_column">Dell</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Sachin Sharma</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Laptop</div>
      <div class="customer_column">dell.com</div>
      <div class="customer_column">31-03-2020</div>
      <div class="customer_column">David</div>
      <div class="customer_column">150</div>
      <div class="customer_column">India</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Good</div>
      <div class="customer_column">500</div>
    </div>
    <div class="customer_row">
      <div class="customer_column">Dell</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Sachin Sharma</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Laptop</div>
      <div class="customer_column">dell.com</div>
      <div class="customer_column">31-03-2020</div>
      <div class="customer_column">David</div>
      <div class="customer_column">150</div>
      <div class="customer_column">India</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Good</div>
      <div class="customer_column">500</div>
    </div>
    <div class="customer_row">
      <div class="customer_column">Dell</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Sachin Sharma</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Laptop</div>
      <div class="customer_column">dell.com</div>
      <div class="customer_column">31-03-2020</div>
      <div class="customer_column">David</div>
      <div class="customer_column">150</div>
      <div class="customer_column">India</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Good</div>
      <div class="customer_column">500</div>
    </div>
    <div class="customer_row">
      <div class="customer_column">Dell</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Sachin Sharma</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Laptop</div>
      <div class="customer_column">dell.com</div>
      <div class="customer_column">31-03-2020</div>
      <div class="customer_column">David</div>
      <div class="customer_column">150</div>
      <div class="customer_column">India</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Good</div>
      <div class="customer_column">500</div>
    </div>
    <div class="customer_row">
      <div class="customer_column">Dell</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Sachin Sharma</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Laptop</div>
      <div class="customer_column">dell.com</div>
      <div class="customer_column">31-03-2020</div>
      <div class="customer_column">David</div>
      <div class="customer_column">150</div>
      <div class="customer_column">India</div>
      <div class="customer_column">Good</div>
      <div class="customer_column">500</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, you could make use of CSS `flex` and `sticky`

```css
.customers_table {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 180px; /* DEMO ONLY to get vert. scrollbars */
}

.customer_row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.customer_headings {
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
}

.customer_headings > div {
  background-color: #4c4c4c;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.customer_row > div {
  flex: 0 0 250px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="customers_table">
  <div class="customer_row customer_headings">
    <div>Company</div>
    <div>Name Heading is too long to fit here and shrinks</div>
    <div>Product</div>
    <div>Site</div>
    <div>Date Added</div>
    <div>Salesperson</div>
    <div>Quote</div>
    <div>Country</div>
    <div>Progress</div>
    <div>Estimate</div>
  </div>
  <div class="customer_row">
    <div>Yey!!</div>
    <div>Sachin Sharma</div>
    <div>Laptop</div>
    <div>dell.com</div>
    <div>31-03-2020</div>
    <div>David</div>
    <div>150</div>
    <div>India</div>
    <div>Good</div>
    <div>500</div>
  </div>
  <div class="customer_row">
    <div>Dell</div>
    <div>Sachin Sharma</div>
    <div>Laptop</div>
    <div>dell.com</div>
    <div>31-03-2020</div>
    <div>David</div>
    <div>150</div>
    <div>India</div>
    <div>Good</div>
    <div>500</div>
  </div>
  <div class="customer_row">
    <div>Dell</div>
    <div>Sachin Sharma</div>
    <div>Laptop</div>
    <div>dell.com</div>
    <div>31-03-2020</div>
    <div>David</div>
    <div>150</div>
    <div>India</div>
    <div>Good</div>
    <div>500</div>
  </div>
  <div class="customer_row">
    <div>Dell</div>
    <div>Sachin Sharma</div>
    <div>Laptop</div>
    <div>dell.com</div>
    <div>31-03-2020</div>
    <div>David</div>
    <div>150</div>
    <div>India</div>
    <div>Good</div>
    <div>500</div>
  </div>
  <div class="customer_row">
    <div>Dell</div>
    <div>Sachin Sharma</div>
    <div>Laptop</div>
    <div>dell.com</div>
    <div>31-03-2020</div>
    <div>David</div>
    <div>150</div>
    <div>India</div>
    <div>Good</div>
    <div>500</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry can't use since I have to show the long text as "Name Heading is too long to fit here...". Moreover `flex` doesn't work in IE10 and earlier. Any other solution?

Comment: Also IE/Edge 15 and earlier versions do not support sticky position.